# hide some middle part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

how to change url for example `http://mysite.com/forum/forum.php?id=1` a `http://forum.mysite.com/forum.php?id=1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want any `/forum/foo` to be `/foo`? If yes then use this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^forum/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
```